# access nested json with ng-repeat doesn't work in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to access orderId with nested json like this

```
var user = [

    {
      'id',1
      'order':[
               {'orderId':12345},
               {'orderId':654321}
               ]

    },
    {
      'id',2
      'order':[
               {'orderId':3333},
               {'orderId':4444}
               ]

    }
    ]
```

I tried

```
<ul ng-repeat="user in user">
<li ng-repeat="order user.order">
{{order.orderId}}
</li>
</ul>
```

one extra question : can ng-repeat use for merely objects json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul ng-repeat="user in user">
<li ng-repeat="order in user.order"> <!----- NEED TO ADD IN ---->
{{order.orderId}}
</li>
</ul>
```

I don't think it is limited to json, it is just a repeat through arrays.

For semantics, I would change your JSON `user` array to `users`:

```
var users = [ // <----------- see here

    {
      'id',1
      'order':[
               {'orderId':12345},
               {'orderId':654321}
               ]

    },
    {
      'id',2
      'order':[
               {'orderId':3333},
               {'orderId':4444}
               ]

    }
    ]
```